# Accuracy Radius for Region Specific ASes

Tags: geoip, maxmind, geoip2

How should we think about the accuracy radius for IP addresses allocated to regional ASes? These often return the city data we would expect, but a much larger accuracy radius. For example, 109.254.127.255 is part of a large block allocated to AS 20590.

- Maxmind returns a postal code and a location for Donetsk, Ukraine (specific)
- Maxmind returns an accuracy radius of 1000km (general)

The AS has an address in Donetsk, Ukraine (https://ipinfo.io/AS20590). Why would the accuracy radius be large, but Maxmind returns a postal code and location consistent with the AS's address? Do you assume it's impossible to geolocate the IP address beyond the country?

I am trying to get accurate regional IP address geolocation.

Comment: IP geolocation is never a 100% accurate. You can see the accuracy published by another provider athttps://www.ip2location.com/data-accuracy